# How to transform list with in a list using jolt library

Tags: java, json, xslt, transformation, jolt

I am trying to transform a JSON into another using Jolt library and not getting the desired output.

Here is my input file.

```json
{
  "maxResults": 150,
  "total": 89,
  "issues": [
    {
      "key": "1",
      "fields": {
        "fixVersions": [
          {
            "self": "FIX1-01",
            "id": "11"
          },
          {
            "self": "FIX1-02",
            "id": "12"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "key": "2",
      "fields": {
        "fixVersions": [
          {
            "self": "FIX2-01",
            "id": "21"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "key": "3",
      "fields": {
        "fixVersions": []
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

and this is the spec file I am using for transformation.

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "issues": {
        "*": {
          "key": "[&1].id",
          "fields": {
            "fixVersions": {
              "*": {
                "self": "[&1].fixVersion.name"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

And I am getting this output

```json
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "fixVersion": {
      "name": [
        "FIX1-01",
        "FIX2-01"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "fixVersion": {
      "name": "FIX1-02"
    },
    "id": "2"
  },
  {
    "id": "3"
  }
]
```

Its not right. What it is doing is it is getting first self field value of each issue and populating it as a array in first fixVersions of the output and getting second self field value and populating it in the second fixVersions. What I want to do is keep the structure as it is in input just change self field name like this.

```json
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "fixVersion": [
      {
        "name": "FIX1-01"
      },
      {
        "name": "FIX1-02"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "fixVersion": [
      {
        "name": "FIX2-01"
      }
    ],
    "id": "2"
  },
  {
    "id": "3"
  }
]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this spec is what you are looking for:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "issues": {
        "*": {
          "key": "[&1].id",
          "fields": {
            "fixVersions": {
              "*": {
                "self": "[&4].fixVersion[&1].name"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Output using it against your input would result into:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "fixVersion": [
      {
        "name": "FIX1-01"
      },
      {
        "name": "FIX1-02"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "fixVersion": [
      {
        "name": "FIX2-01"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "3"
  }
]
```

Please note the change on the indexes you are using to rebuild the fixVersion (needs to take into account whe issues index as well) list, you were missing this:

```
[&4].fixVersion[&1].name
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

As you have used the XSLT tag and the Java tag you could use XSLT and/or XQuery 3 with Saxon 9 and use e.g.

```
declare namespace output = "http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";

declare option output:method 'text';

declare variable $json as xs:string external := '{
      "maxResults": 150,
      "total": 89,
      "issues": [
        {
          "key": "1",
          "fields": {
            "fixVersions": [
              {
                "self": "FIX1-01",
                "id": "11"
              },
              {
                "self": "FIX1-02",
                "id": "12"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "2",
          "fields": {
            "fixVersions": [
              {
                "self": "FIX2-01",
                "id": "21"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "3",
          "fields": {
            "fixVersions": []
          }
        }
      ]
    }';


transform(map {
    'source-node' : json-to-xml($json),
    'stylesheet-node' : <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0">
      <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
      <xsl:template match="*:string[@key = 'self']">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:attribute name="key">name</xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
})?output => xml-to-json(map { 'indent' : true() })
```

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxZ8R